# play quicktime from browser

Tags: opensuse, quicktime

When I try to play a quicktime trailer from http://trailers.apple.com/ my OpenSUSE 12.1 system freezes. This can sometimes be so extreme that I have to force shutdown the machine.

Is it somehow possible to get quicktime for UNIX systems like OpenSUSE?

**Systeminformation**

OS: OpenSUSE 12.1 (default installation)

Browser: Firefox

Plugin: No Plugins

Comment: Please, edit your question and add some information on the environment. E.g. Which browser do you use? Which plug-in do you use to play quicktime files?

Comment: Did my edit help?

Comment: **No Plugins**? I do not think so ...

Comment: It's a default OpenSUSE installation, I suppose that there can't be any Plugins (unless you tell me how to find out)

Comment: I was writing it in the answer ;-)

Comment: No Problem, hold on to me I am trying to solve the problem with your solution ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you have some trouble with **mplayer firefox plugin** (installed by default on openSuSE).

In any case, you can try to replace it with **gecko-mediaplayer** plug-in:

1. Run firefox and write `about:plugins` in the address bar.
2. Check carefully if there is any plugin that manages *quicktime* files.
3. In case, remove that plugin. E.g. if mplayer:

   ```
   sudo zypper remove mplayerplug-in
   ```
4. Add *packman* repository to your package management system:

   ```
   sudo zypper ar -f -n packman http://packman.inode.at/suse/openSUSE_12.1 packman
   ```
5. Install gecko-mediaplayer plug-in from packman:

   ```
   sudo zypper install gecko-mediaplayer
   ```
6. Restart firefox and check `about:plugins`.
7. Try and let us know.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm, thanx for the speed help :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does no longer work for SUSE 13.2 in 2015. There is no gecko-mediaplayer on the packman repo for this version (at least for the x86_64 architecture)