# Playing quicktime movies in SuSE13.2

Tags: opensuse, video, mediaplayer, quicktime

How can I play a Quicktime movie using SuSE 13.2?

I have read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28392/play-quicktime-from-browser) and the accepted answer there. Unfortunately, it does no longer work with SuSE 13.2. I tried to find an rpm for gecko-mediaplayer and succeeded in finding one for SuSE 13.1; but I wasn't able to install it because the chain of dependencies eventually broke down with "mplayer2".

Comment: post a link to a sample video? I have 13.2 and if I can see it I might be able to determine the packages I have installed for it.

Comment: The video in question is private and was created with a digicam. I'll try to get a less private sample video, but it may take some time.